# JOIN not working in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am working on a project with PHP and MySQL. I am trying to run a SQL query where I need to fetch data from 5 tables. I'm getting an error on my query.

```
$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$estId = $value->estId;

$sql = 'SELECT establishments.id, establishments.name, 
               establishments.stay_value, establishments.latitude, 
               establishments.longitude, establishments.description,
               establishments.address,
               facilities.id, facilities.name,
               accomodations.id,accomodations.name
        FROM establishments
        INNER JOIN (establishments_facilities
                    INNER JOIN facilities
                    ON establishments_facilty.facility_id = facilities.id) 
        ON establishments.id = establishments_facility.id
        INNER JOIN (establishments_accommodations
                    INNER JOIN accommodations
                    ON establishments_accommodations.accommodation_d = accomodations.id)      
        WHERE establishments.id ="'.$estId .'" ';

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $json_obj = $row;
    }
    $json_obj['success'] = true;
    echo json_encode($json_obj);
}
```

My 5 tables are:

**establishments**

```
1   id    
2   user_id    
3   name    
4   logo    
5   description    
6   email    
7   latitude    
8   longitude    
9   stay_value
```

**accomodations**

```
1   id    
2   name
```

**facilities**

```
1   id    
2   name
```

**establishments_accommodations**

```
1   id    
2   establishment_id    
3   accommodation_id
```

**establishments_facilities**

```
1   id    
2   establishment_id    
3   facility_id
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: where do you get the $estId from?, on the 'where' clause i mean.
And whats the error?

Comment: Might be useful to tell us what the error is...

Comment: $value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$estId = $value->estId;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you wrote is hard to read and you should use alias for better readability and also join syntax does not look correct, here is the query with proper alias

```
SELECT 
e.id, 
e.name, 
e.stay_value, 
e.latitude, 
e.longitude, 
e.description,
e.address,
f.id, 
f.name,
a.id,
a.name
FROM establishments e 
INNER JOIN establishments_facilities ef on e.id = ef.id
INNER JOIN facilities f ON ef.facility_id = f.id          
INNER JOIN establishments_accommodations ea on ea.establishment_id = ef.establishment_id
INNER JOIN accommodations a ON ea.accommodation_d = a.id      
WHERE e.id ={some value}
```

Now in PHP you may have something as

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
e.id, 
e.name, 
e.stay_value, 
e.latitude, 
e.longitude, 
e.description,
e.address,
f.id, 
f.name,
a.id,
a.name
FROM establishments e 
INNER JOIN establishments_facilities ef on e.id = ef.id
INNER JOIN facilities f ON ef.facility_id = f.id          
INNER JOIN establishments_accommodations ea on ea.establishment_id = ef.establishment_id
INNER JOIN accommodations a ON ea.accommodation_d = a.id      
where e.id = '".$estId."'";
```

Note that `where e.id = '".$estId."'"` is vulnerable to sq-injection, so better to use prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I ll keep in mind the changes you suggested. However I am still getting the error

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in line 39

which is <pre>$result = $conn->query($sql);</pre>

Comment: What if you run the same query on mysql directly by setting some `e.id = 'someval'` ?

Comment: So the query problem is fixed, now check if the `$conn` is available in the code also check if the `$estId = $value->estId;` value is set. The problem lies in either of these 2.

Comment: note that you are doing inner join and this mean all the table should have data and meets the joining clause, `id` is coming from 3 tables so you need to use alias for 2 of them something as `f.id as fid,a.id as aid `

Comment: Thanks for the help! Everything works Fine! I will sort out the n0n-object problem